# Dar estilo a un reporte segun una condicion - ireport

Tags: base-de-datos, ireport, reporte

tengo el presente inconveniente, estoy realizando un reporte el mismo trae dias. Los dias habiles no deberian pintarse, los fines de semana si y los feriados tambien. Logre que se pinten los fines de semana. Pero me resta que pueda pintar los francos. Para saber que dias son feriados, dentro de la query se ejecuta una funcion definida dentro de la DB que va comparando los dias ingresados por parametro con los dias feriados registrados en una tabla, devolviendo un 1 o un 0 segun ese dia sea o no un dia feriado. Cuestion que no logro encontrar la forma de que me pinte esos dias ingresando dentro del style la condicion para que eso ocurra.

Necesitaria entonces lograr que el ireport (version 5.6.0) tome la funcion que defini en la db Y me pinte tambien al generarse el reporte los dias feriados.

```
select
emp.emp_id ID_EMP,
emp.emp_last_name  ||', '|| emp.emp_first_name NOMBRE,
(select pc.pc_payroll_id
from att_daily_pc_exc exc
inner join att_pay_codes pc ON pc.pc_pay_code = exc.pc_pay_code
where exc.de_date = f.fecha
and exc.emp_emplo = emp.emp_emplo
and exc.pc_pay_code in(200,199,204,213,195,197,207,193,293,191,190,189,215,214,188,194,192,186,203,187,205,296,297,298,294,295,211,198,212,202,100)) CODES,
f.fecha as FECHA,
***ATT_CHECK_IS_HOLIDAY(f.fecha)as esFeriado***
from att_fecha f,
att_employees emp
inner join att_temp_emplos temp ON temp.emp_emplo = emp.emp_emplo
where f.fecha BETWEEN $P{date1} AND $P{date2}
order by 1,4
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega tu jrxml, o por lo menos el(los) elemento(s) `<style>`. ¿Cómo se llama el campo de los días feriados? y ¿A cuál campo quieres aplicar el estilo?.

Comment: Ahi agregue, el campo de los dias feriados es una funcion que le pongo como alias "esFeriado", pero este campo no forma parte del reporte, es solo a los efectos de que el mismo sirva para distinguir los dias feriados. El campo al cual le quiero aplicar el estilo es el campo fecha. La idea es que la columna del reporte que muestre ese campo se pinte si el dia es un feriado o un fin de semana, la funcion que pase arriba la uso para que saber que dia es feriado y asi se pueda pintar esa columna

Comment: Intenta agregar `esFeriado` a un grupo de columnas y usa la variable creada en la expresión de condición. Agrega a tu pregunta el xml del crosstab.